# React and Redux: Payload Not Appearing Within Reducer State Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

In the following reducer file, when a user logs in the state is updated with the payload coming from the actions file. In my state, I have a user object in which I want to store the payload. However, in my redux dev tool, I noticed that the payload is appearing outside of the user object instead of within it as a result user object shows as the default value of null. Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

//Login Reducer Fille

```
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoading: false,
  user: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
    return{
      ...state,
      ...action.payload,
      isAuthenticated: true,
      isLoading: false
    };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

//Login Action File

```
export const login = ({email, password, history}) => dispatch =>{
  const config = {
    headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

 
  const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});
  axios.post('/api/user/login/', body, config)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    })
    history.push('/dashboard')
  })
    .catch(err =>{
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'LOGIN_FAIL'));
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: What is the action dispatched? My crystal ball is broken so can't see what `res.data` in the dispatched action is.

Comment: Token, user id, name, email, and image. I want token to be assigned to token object and the remaining payload assigned to user object.

Comment: Does this work: `const {token,...user}=action.payload; return {...state,token,user, otherstuff}`

Comment: Yes! Wow I can't believe I did not think of that approach you mentioned. Was trying to figure this out for hours. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also is it okay if i return token and user like this: token: token, user: user

Comment: Yes `{value}` is [shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) for `{value:value}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the reducer return method in the LOGIN_SUCCESS case block to this one

```
return {
  ...state,
  user:action.payload,
  isAuthenticated: true,
  isLoading: false
};
```

Comment: I already tried that and the issue with that is, although the payload is assigned to user object as desired, my token object is left with null. The token is not assigned in the token object like it did with ...action.payload

Comment: then you have to dispatch in the action like this dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: { token:7845 , user : {what ever value in user's object}  }
    })

then your spread operator work as you want

Comment: Thank you Ali Raza. The approach HMR mentioned above did exactly what I wanted. Thank you for taking the time to respond though.